# Spring + JUnit4 + JPA/Hibernate - Transaction isolation weirdness?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions, junit

I am trying to test my Spring backed JPA/Hibernate DAO using JUnit and H2. I have a `@Before` annotated initialization method which loads a SQL file up and creates a base data set for each test. Transactions are setup so that after every test, it's rolled back and it starts again. So, this base data set is created for each individual test, then rolled back afterward.

This all works great, except I see oddness with unique constraints. I am fairly new to all of these technologies, so maybe I'm just overlooking something. I'd like to be able to test that the unique constraints are working as expected on certain values.

First, the `init()` method:

```
@Before
public void init() throws IOException {        
    // Setup default data
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(getSqlFromFile());
    query.executeUpdate();        
}
```

Now a test method demonstrating issue:

```
public void testSaveExistingNonUniqueUsername() {
    // EXISTING_USER_ID added in @Before annotated init() method
    User existingUser = testDao.get(EXISTING_USER_ID); 
    // Set to a non-unique username also added in @Before annotated init() method
    existingUser.setUsername(SECOND_EXISTING_USER); 
    // Save. Here I would expect an exception because of the unique constraint violation. None. Save method simply calls EntityManager.persist()
    testDao.save(existingUser);

    Long count = testDao.countByUsername(SECOND_EXISTING_USER);
    // Count method still returns 1
    assertEquals(Long.valueOf(1), count); 

    // Re-load the user
    User savedUser  = testDao.get(EXISTING_USER_ID); 

    // Fails. Username is set to the non-unique value after re-loading, even though the count returned 1, it appears we have two with the same username
    assertEquals(savedUser.getUsername(), EXISTING_USER); 
}
```

I'm loading an existing user, changing the username to a non-unique value, and then saving.

Here is my User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements DomainObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, length=25, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, length=50)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled = true;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="role", referencedColumnName="name")    
    private UserRole role;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="contact_details_id")    
    private UserContactDetail contactDetails;

    // .... getters and setters omitted .....

}
```

You'll note that I also have updatable and nullable set to false for Username, yet it still allows me to make the change.

The Test class itself is annotated with the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/test/resources/spring/spring-test-master.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback =  true)
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@TestExecutionListeners( {
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
```

It uses my production configuration, but I override the data source bean with an H2 datasource. It's completely vanilla, nothing fancy.

The test method demonstrates that the data loaded in the `init()` method is accessible, as the IDs are present and the entities load. However, the unique constraints don't seem to be working within this transaction.

However, in the following test, they do:

```
@Test(expected=DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public void testSaveExistingNonUniqueUsername() {
    // getValidTestUser() just creates a new User() and fills it in with valid data. No ID is set.
    User firstUser = getValidTestUser();
    testDao.save(firstUser);
    // secondUser will be identical to the first user, but will have a different ID when saved
    User secondUser = getValidTestUser();
    // This DOES throw an exception
    testDao.save(secondUser);
}
```

I'm hoping I am just overlooking something simple. Any help or explanation as to why this might occur would be appreciated.

DB Connection configuration:

```
# configure h2 data source
jdbc.url=jdbc\:h2\:mem\:junitTest;DB_CLOSE_DELAY\=-1
jdbc.user=sa
jdbc.pass=
jdbc.driver=org.h2.Driver

# configure hibernate specific properties
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.cache.provider_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}" 
      p:url="${jdbc.url}" 
      p:username="${jdbc.user}"
      p:password="${jdbc.pass}"/>
```

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

<util:properties id="jpaProperties">
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>       
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"          
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:persistenceUnitName="PersistenceUnit"
      p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect"
      p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
      p:jpaProperties-ref="jpaProperties" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"          
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your User domain entity you have marked the username field as updatable false. Therefore hibernate won't include that field in any update statements. So changing the username and calling save won't change anything.

Since the username is the key for this table why not use it as the @Id?

Comment: That makes sense, except that in the demonstration test case I am re-loading the entity by ID and the username appears to have been updated. Am I running into some kind of caching issue here where it is re-using the same entity?

Comment: As per the @Id question, this is running against MySQL in production. My understanding (though this may be a misconception I have picked up along the way) is that a numeric ID is much faster than a string in MySQL, so I tend to use them.

Comment: Thanks Alex. After some more reading I see the issue. I did not realize that the same entity instance was returned within the same context.

Comment: Yes that's certainly true. Takes quite a bit of reading/playing around to work out exactly what's going on right! It always makes perfect sense in the end but the journey there can be interesting! Glad you worked it out.